# Inherited EXTERNAL_Storage permission at targetSDK33

Tags: permissions

The app I am running has a case that uses external storage, so I added the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in the manifest. For target API level 29, I used the reqeustLegacyExternalStorage = "true" option, and for target API level 30, I used the preserveLegacyExternalStorage="true" option to ensure that if the app was already installed from API level 29, it could continue using external storage by inheriting the permission.

Until target API level 32, there was no mention of external storage-related changes. However, with the recent update to target API level 33, it is stated in the Android developer guide that READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission has no effect and is divided into three separate permissions.

After testing the update to target API level 33, I found that for apps that were already inheriting permissions from target API level 29 and above, the EXTERNAL_STORAGE-related permissions still functioned as before.

So, is it correct that the EXTERNAL_STORAGE-related permissions that were inherited previously continue to be valid even in target API level 33?

In the Android developer guide, there is no explicit mention of permission inheritance for EXTERNAL_STORAGE-related permissions. Does this mean that EXTERNAL_STORAGE-related permissions are invalidated only in the case of a fresh installation, and not for apps that were already installed before the target API level update?

Comment: Please define plattform

Comment: this occurs at arm64 with AOS12 and AOS13.